# Adding rows in matrix using java

Tags: java

I have created a matrix in java using only loops. But I wanted to show the total of the row at the end. I have been trying to figure this out and I cannot come up with a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code I have so far

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num = 4;
        int product = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++) {

                 product = j * i;

                System.out.printf("\t" + product);


            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say total of the row, what does that mean? The number of rows? The sum of the numbers in a row? Also, what have you tried. Even just putting print statements in the loops would illustrate exactly what it is doing up each iteration. You have to show some sort of effort here.

Comment: don't you think `sum of column` instead of row?

Comment: where is your matrix? right now you only have 2 encapsuled for-loops...

Comment: right now i get this matrix
1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12
4 8 12 16

i want to be able to do this
1 2 3 4 = 10
2 4 6 8 = 20
3 6 9 12 = 30
4 8 12 16 = 40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to implement something such as: `int total = 0;` then on each cycle of the loop update accordingly...`total = total + x;`

Comment: right now i get this matrix
1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12
4 8 12 16

i want to be able to do this
1 2 3 4 = 10
2 4 6 8 = 20
3 6 9 12 = 30
4 8 12 16 = 40

Comment: So just reset the total variable after the end of each loop, and you'll be set. Set a conditional to print the total once the last element of the row has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly what you should do is have a field that keeps track of the accumulated sum of the columns.

I'll give an example based on your code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num = 4;
    int product = 0;
    int rowSum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        rowSum = 0; //reset for each row.
        for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++) {

            product = j * i;
            rowSum += product; //rowSum = rowSum + product.

            System.out.printf("\t" + product);


        }
        System.out.printf("\t = " + rowSum); //this should give you = SUM at the end of the line.
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}